# When is the natural map of Tate cohomology an isomorphism?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, class-field-theory, duality

First of all I want to say that **I am not at all an expert in Group cohomology** . Recently I attended a seminar where the speaker  mentioned about something called *Tate cohomology groups* which in someway relate group homology and group cohomology in one sequence.

**My question is the following:**

Is there any result towards the characterization of the finite groups $G$ and $G$-modules $A$ such that the natural map $N:H_0(G,A) \rightarrow H^{0}(G,A)$ appearing in Tate cohomology is an isomorphism of groups?

(My reference is  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_cohomology_group)

It seems interesting to me because when $N$ is an isomorphism it represents some sort of notion of *duality* between group homology and group cohomology at the zeroth level.

I asked this question to the speaker but did not get satisfactory answer . So I am asking here for an answer / partial answer to my question.

I  **apologise in advance** if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: It holds, for example, if A is a projective Z[G]-module (III.1.1(c) in Brown's book 'Cohomology of Groups')

Comment: @DrewHeard Thanks for the Reference. I guess you mean Chapter 3, Section 1  in Brown's book. I have the first edition of the book with me but I could not find 1(c) in section 1 of chapter 3 there. Is it a different edition?

Comment: @DrewHeard Thanks I found it. It was in the Exercise.